# Installing Hive 2.1.0 Interactive Query (LLAP) on Kerberized HDP 2.6.2 environment

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-zookeeper, kerberos, hadoop2

I had a lot of issues surrounding the installation/activation of Hive 2.1.0 on our HDP 2.6.2 cluster. But finally I got it working, so I wanted to share the steps involved with the community. I got these steps from different sources, which I will also mention below each step. My specifications:

- Clustered HDP 2.6.2 (hortonworks) environment
- Kerberos
- Hive 1.2.1000 -> Hive 2.1.0

**Step 1: Enable Hive Interactive Query**

Follow the steps on the Hortonworks website. This includes enabling YARN pre-emption and some other Yarn settings. After adjusting YARN your can enable Hive Interactive Query via Ambari. You also have to specify a default queue that is at least 20% of your total cluster capacity.

[Source](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.6.2/bk_hive-performance-tuning/content/ch_hive-perf-tuning-intro.html)

**Step 2: Kerberos related settings**

Make sure you add the following settings to the *custom hiveserver2-interactive site* in Ambari. Where ${REALMNAME} is the name of your LDAP realm.

```
hive.llap.zk.sm.keytab.file=/etc/security/keytabs/hive.llap.zk.sm.keytab
hive.llap.zk.sm.principal=hive/_HOST@${REALMNAME}
hive.llap.daemon.keytab.file=/etc/security/keytabs/hive.service.keytab
hive.llap.daemon.service.principal=hive/_HOST@${REALMNAME}
```

Now you have to put those 2 keytabs (basically the same keytabs) on **every** YARN node. This can be done manually or through Ambari (Kerberos service). Make sure those keytabs are `chown hive:hadoop` and have a `chmod 440` (group read).

Note: you also need a user *hive* on all those nodes.

[Source](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.6.2/bk_command-line-installation/content/install_llap_secure.html)

**Step 3: Zookeeper configuration**

It could be that Hive is not recognized by Zookeeper, this will give acl errors when trying to start the HiveServer2 Interactive. To cope with this issue I added the right hive acl nodes through a zookeeper client host.

```
    su -
    # First, authenticate with the hive keytab
    kinit hive/'hostname' -kt /etc/security/keytabs/hive.service.keytab
    # Second, connect to a zookeeper client on your cluster
    /usr/hdp/current/zookeeper-server/bin/zkCli.sh -server ${ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT}
    # Third, check the current status of the user-hive acl
    getAcl /llap-sasl/user-hive
    # Fourth, If this is not there create the following nodes
    create /llap-sasl/user-hive "" sasl:hive:cdrwa,world:anyone:r
    create /llap-sasl/user-hive/llap0 "" sasl:hive:cdrwa,world:anyone:r
    create /llap-sasl/user-hive/llap0/workers "" sasl:hive:cdrwa,world:anyone:r
    # Fifth, change the llap-sasl node to add the user hive
    setAcl /llap-sasl sasl:hive:cdrwa,world:anyone:r
```

[Source 1](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/90705/hive-llap-fails-with-invalidacl-for-llap-sasluser.html), [Source 2](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/86100/llap-error.html)

Basically, this should work for Kerberized environments. If you got errors related to ACL, go back to your Zookeeper settings and look if everything is fine. If you have errors related to a missing Hive user, you should look of the hive user is added correctly to the nodes. If you have an error related to Kerberos (principal or keytabs) look if the keytabs are on the designated (YARN) nodes with the correct rights.